# Mixing live output of inputs from separate audio interfaces on Mac Ventura aggregate audio device for Logic Pro

Tags: audio, ventura, logic

I have a mostly hardware midi studio set up where I have 2 Arturia Audiofuse 8Pres (one ADAT-piped into the other) on a USB-3 line and I'm running out of inputs so I purchased a SSL 12, hooked it to another USB line, created an Aggregate device and set up a test project in Logic Pro (this is all on a Mac Studio Ultra running ventura 13.5.2 and the latest Logic Pro.)

My workflow is such that I usually compose almost everything on the Midi hardware before I record anything so I was hoping the aggregate device would act to mix all the inputs and let me hear them "live" through the same output (the Audiofuse 8Pre stereo out) but that's not working.  I am able to record through each device, but I can only hear what's coming through the inputs of either on the outputs of the interface through which a given input is coming.

[image: Screen capture of Audio devices panel showing Audio's 8Pre and SSL12 aggregate device][image: Logic Pro Audio Settings]

My studio monitors are set up so that I can listen to music via the External Headphone jack when the Audiofuses aren't powered up so I tried setting the Logic Pro output device to "External headphone" but then I couldn't hear anything live.

Is hearing the live input of an instrument input into one interface from the output of another interface on a separate USB line something that should be possible, or do I need to look for another interface solution?  If so, does anyone have a recommendation for anything rack-mountable that will let me get up in the 24-32 input range?